# MS Access query sum up the values when certain columns match

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access database holding shoot days for commercials and line items tied to each shoot day.

So I'll have something like...

```
Shoot Day      ......      Total
 Travel                     400
 Travel                     150
 Travel                     200
   1                        350
   1                        275
   2                        850
   2                        500
  ...                       ...
```

This goes on for a while. I want a query to return something like

```
Shoot Day      .......     Total
 Travel                     750
   1                        625
   2                       1350
  ...                       ...
```

So I'd like it to add up the total column whenever there is a match in the Shoot Day column.

I'd love some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something on the lines of:

```
 SELECT [Shoot Day], Sum([Total])
 FROM Table
 GROUP BY [Shoot Day]
```

Comment: Surprised I couldn't figure that out. Thank you!

Comment: The query design window can be quite useful.